# readtext = new String(buff, 0, read)......is it a string, int , or array?

Tags: java, telnet

Im confused. This is part of a telnet app and I want it to return a string and update a textarea. I tried to update the textarea from inside the method which is in the same class with textArea.setText but that does not work and I know we should be calling the method and returning the string. Yes I know I should remove the "void" but when I try it says the method returns an int? I want it to return a string with the text from the server. If I print to console it prints exactly the text i want....Arg!!! Also Im using the apache commons library.

```
public static void read() throws IOException {

   String readtext;

   byte[] buff = new byte[1024];

   int read;

   if((read = telnetClient.getInputStream().read(buff)) > 0) {

    readtext = new String(buff, 0, read);

    //return readtext;

       //System.out.println(new String(buff, 0, read));

    System.out.println(readtext);

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer does not return a String. You need to add String to the method signature and return the `readtext` variable in order to get the text that you want.

Try this:

```
public static String read() throws IOException {
   String readtext;    
   byte[] buff = new byte[1024];    
   int read;

   if((read = telnetClient.getInputStream().read(buff)) > 0) {    
       readtext = new String(buff, 0, read);
   }
    return readtext;    
   }
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you explained why yours works and his doesn't. If a return statement is found within normal execution flow, and is followed by more code, the compiler will flag up all later code as unreachable, and will refuse to compile. With maloneys approach however, the return statement is the very last thing in the method and is therefore correct :)